# Transaction consisting from transfers of 0 USDT

Tags: etherscan, contract-invocation, scam

I noted in transaction history of my account a strange transaction for 0 USDT.
Interesting, transaction consists of 50 subtransactions all of which have zero value.

How it is possible without private key to transfer any valuefrom account? And who did pay txFees for it.
Private key does not seem compromised as all tokens and ETH on that account kept its place.

Transaction
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d39061bbd8c9953ab9f4793da18d437d8ac2045032657cca7e01d58e3195aed

Contract that created it
https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x732e9b5f59c9a442db18f7d57dd2bbfc804281cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC20 tokens have a transfer function which allows you to send your own tokens, but also an approve and transferFrom function which allows you to approve a smart contract to take some of your tokens, and then the smart contract to take it.

The [USDT token](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code) has no code in its transferFrom to prevent someone from taking 0 tokens out of your account even if you haven't approved any. The transaction will go through and post an event saying 0 tokens were transferred.

The account which sent the transaction (
0x84eb60e6732848f837f48402dcfff25e3d3d9304) paid the fees, as usual.

Why are they doing this? No idea. Perhaps they are trying to fool blockchain analysis tools.

Answer (score 1):

Carefull with this I think it is a new form of scamming that hackers are trying to do:

https://mirror.xyz/x-explore.eth/cL3d_CyNujXq8XY7ueP4omNXx_IY1EG5Dz0FD0vJ90M